# I got error missing template with many duplicated not existed action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, csv

#### What's problem?

In rails 4.2.5.1, I make one action for importing csv. For this one, I use [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), and I'll update record with this uploaded csv. And My record is updated succefully. But problem is after that.

After updating record, I want to reload page. But error is out.

```
(1.1ms)  COMMIT
System Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "systems".* FROM "systems"  ORDER BY "systems"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3622ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template systems/import, application/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import, smart_listing/import with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Penguin/Desktop/Dev_Web/chartTest/app/views"
  * "/Users/Penguin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/Users/Penguin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/smart_listing-1.1.2/app/views"
:
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
```

You can see many duplicated `smart_listing/import`. And `systems/import` `application/import`, too. But these are not existed method. So I think I make some mistake. What makes this annoying error? Thanks.

#### Code

```
#routes.rb
resources :systems do
  get 'export', action: 'export', on: :collection, defaults: { format: 'csv'}
  put 'import', action: 'import', on: :collection
  patch 'import', action: 'import', on: :collection
end

# system.rb
class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import_csv(setting)
    CSV.foreach(setting.path, headers: true) do |row|
      if System.new(row.to_hash).valid?
        System.last.update(row.to_hash)
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end

# system_controller.rb
class SystemsController < ApplicationController
  def import
    respond_to do |format|
      if System.import_csv(params[:setting])
        format.html { redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Home was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :import, status: :ok, location: index }
      else
        format.html { render :import }
        format.json { render status: :bad_request}
      end
    end
  end
end

<!-- systems/index.html.erb -->
<%= form_tag import_systems_path, multipart: true, id: 'import' do %>
    <div class="btn btn-lightDarkTwt" id="setting-import">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span>
      <span>export</span>
      <%= file_field_tag :setting %>
    </div>
<% end %>

// system.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#setting').fileupload({
    url: location.href + '/import',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'put',
    autoUpdate: true,
    add: function(e, data) {
      data.submit();
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: change `location: index` to `location: url_for(action: :index)`. You are explicitly executing index action here.

Comment: @BroiSatse Nope. Nothing was changed. Same error is outputted.

Comment: Could you give some more context from your log? It seems you are sending `json` request, and your controller is trying to find `index.json` template which you don't have. What is the behaviour you want to achieve there?